# counting total number of successful and failed upload in yii

Tags: php, html, yii

My code looks like this right now. I want to add a total on the top of page that counts the total number of successful and failed data.

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Upload File'); ?>

<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'csv_file'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model, 'csv_file'); ?><?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?><?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?><?php $this->endWidget();if (!empty($Results)) {
echo "<h3><font face='arial'><b> Upload Results </b></h3>";
echo implode(", ", $firstLine) . "<br/>";

foreach ($Results as $result) {
    echo implode(", ", $result["data"]) . "<br/>";
    echo "<div style='padding-left: 20px'>";
    echo "<span style='color: red;'>" . $result["message"] . "</span> <br/>";

    foreach ($result["model"]->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
        echo "Attribute $attribute has the following errors:" . "<br/>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "<li style='color: red;'>" . $error . "</li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

}
}
?>
```

- Total records
- Total successful
- Total failed

How do i do this? Is there anyway to do it in the view itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval if this could be a solution

```
$numRecords = 0;
$numErrors = 0;
$numRecordsWithError = 0;
foreach ($Results as $result) {
    $numRecords++;

    echo implode(", ", $result["data"]) . "<br/>";
    echo "<div style='padding-left: 20px'>";
    echo "<span style='color: red;'>" . $result["message"] . "</span> <br/>";

    $flagRecErr = false;
    foreach ($result["model"]->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
        if ($flagRecErr == false){
          $flagRecErr = true;
          $numRecordsWithError++;
        }
        $numErrors++;
        echo "Attribute $attribute has the following errors:" . "<br/>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "<li style='color: red;'>" . $error . "</li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

}
}
echo "<div>Num Records " .  $numRecords . "</div><br />";
echo "<div>Num Errors " .  $numErrors . "</div><br />";
echo "<div>Num Record with Errors " .  $numRecordsWithError . "</div><br />";
```

Comment: this works but it is giving me error and record report. I want to display total number of data, count of all error and count of total record only instead of each individual count!

Comment: ManufactureDate, Address, Number, State
12/15/2014, , 700 halo dr, 32451567890, CA
Upload failed. 
Attribute Date has the following errors:
Date already exists.
Attribute Number has the following errors:
 Number already exists.
Records 1
Errors 2

I want it to be displayed as
Total records: 244
Total successful upload: 230
Total Error/failed upload: 14

Comment: And now you have only total and error/failed upload ... is missing the successful upload?.. is the difference between total - error ? or is more complex?

Comment: Then I have add a } at the bottom i don't know if this solve your probem but i think you should place the code suggested (the $num.. initialize and the echo ) where you retan is is right.. probably the  counter and the echo need to be place outside loop / foreach..

Comment: is there any way to add this to the controller and pass params? it is not displaying it the way i wanted it to. Thank you

Comment: Yes yiu can do in controller.. and pass to a view .. post this as a new  question with your controller and eventually action code

Comment: ok. this is working now when i add it outside the foreach loop but it is getting printed at the bottom of the page. how do i change that and add it to the top instead

Comment: The totale are calculated while you print the results and the errors and then are available at the end of the process.. if you want in the header you must two step a first when you eval your result but don't echo the result for calculate the total. print the total and then repeat the process for printing result and error....Well if my answer for counting is right please mark as acceppted.. is useful rate it too.

Comment: i got it . thank you for your help. i have one small issue. instead of displaying the total number of error, how do i display the total number of records with the error?

Comment: Well if my answer is right plase markit as accepted and as useful too..I have update the answer with code that can manage your last request too..